# ¿ejecutar correctamente script PHP con tareas CRON?

Tags: php, script, cron

Tengo un script en PHP para llenar unos datos a MySQL y copiar unos archivos a carpetas que el mismo script crea.

Cuando ejecuto mi script desde la terminal funciona todo bien...

Cuando inicio el CRON para que ejecute mi script solo llena los datos, mas no crea las carpetas, intente solo creando las carpetas pero aun asi nada por parte del cron.

```
*/1 * * * * php /var/www/html/Servidor/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

puede ser por falta de permisos.

```
chmod -R 777 la_carpeta
```

Esto cambiara los permisos..